# How is this markup fixing the error?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-binding

In a custom VF page I get the following error :-

> System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Campaign.Product__c
>
> Error is in expression '{!CreateMeetingNote}' in component  in page campaignmeetingnote: Class.CampaignDetailButtonController.CreateMeetingNote: line 54, column 1

and the referenced line 54 is

```
  if(campaign.Product__c != null)
```

Now I can fix this by adding the following VF markup

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Campaign.Product__c}" rendered="false" />
```

and without changing any SOQL (not that there is any in my controller class anyway...) the error goes away.

I'm happy that it's fixed, but I'd be happier still if I understood *why* this fixes this issue.  Can someone explain the behaviours I'm seeing here please?

Comment: NB : I don't need Campaign.Product__c for anything on my page from a user perspective, only in the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

standard controller automatically adds fields, that are displayed on VF page, as those, that should be queried. So when you are adding `<apex:outputText value="{!Campaign.Product__c}" rendered="false" />` standard controller includes `Campaign.Product__c` field in query

if you don't want to add this markup to VF page, you can add desired fields in constructor of extension by means of [addFields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) method

> When a Visualforce page is loaded, the fields accessible to the page
>   are based on the fields referenced in the Visualforce markup. This
>   method adds a reference to each field specified in fieldNames so that
>   the controller can explicitly access those fields as well.

```
public Campaign camp {get; set;}
public Extension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    initRecord(controller);
}
private void initRecord(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        controller.addFields(
            new List<String> {
                'Product__c',
            }
        );
    }
    camp = (Campaign)controller.getRecord();
}
```

Comment: Ah, so it's a means of extending the list of fields that StandardController returns by default.  That's very useful, particularly when reusing a controller class for a different (but related to the same object) VF page.  Thanks for explaining/clarifying.

Comment: Is there a reason you add that check for Test context in that example?  Does this not work in Test mode?

Comment: You can use this sort of construction with less uncovered code (like list construction). Put as little as you possibly can inside `Test.isRunningTest()`. If you one-line it, you can actually get "100%" coverage.